# imagej status bar coordinate display

Tags: imagej

Does anyone know of a way to increase the number of digits displayed in ImageJ's status bar? This is normally not a problem if pixel coordinates are displayed, however once a scale is applied only two digits in the display is no longer sufficient depending on the scale factor.

Answer (score 0):

ImageJ displays the coordinates of the cursor position with the help of [`ImagePlus#getLocationAsString(x,y)`](https://github.com/imagej/imagej1/blob/957ae0977253067bf7b370d7191553e25e972388/ij/ImagePlus.java#L2082-2103), which in turn uses [`IJ.d2s(double n)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/IJ.html#d2s%28double%29) to format the coordinates. The problem would be solved if [`IJ.d2s(double x, int significantDigits, int maxDigits)`](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/ij/IJ.html#d2s%28double,%20int,%20int%29) was used instead.

Feel free to write to the [ImageJ mailing list](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/list.html), where Wayne Rasband (the developer of ImageJ 1.x) will likely pick it up and add the feature if he thinks it's appropriate.

As a workaround, you might want to press the ***alt*** key while moving the mouse, switching to pixel coordinates instead of calibrated coordinates in the status bar (see [here](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/docs/guide/146-Part-IV.html#sub:Status-bar)).